# Add link to topic list after new topic or comment submission

Tags: 6, redirection, nodes

I would like that, when users submit a new topic or posts a reply in a forum, they would be redirected to the topics list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's count of ways to do it, one of these: [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. Just add condition on node or comment adding, and add action for redirecting. For taking correct forum page of node or comment, I assume you should enable "php filter" and add php code that got forum taxonomy term and redirect to certain page.

Comment: The php part is my problem... would you be able to elaborate?